# Access printer through Wifi from android device

Tags: java, android, sockets, printing, printer-control-language

I am developing a Billing Application in `android`.

My hardware requirements are : `Android` tab , `WiFi` device , Printer.

My application Ui have input controls. After filled inputs ,values move to SQLite database by clicking submit button.
when i click the submit button , i want to take printout with those details via `wifi`.

Many `android` apps available in market. But i want to customize within my application. Is any better `API` available for this?

I want to access printer via `Wifi` from my android application. I searched in google. I didn't get better solution for this.

Help for me frndz!

Comment: refer this url http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html

Comment: My printer is didn't have WiFi option. It connected via switch. It have seperate IP address. So I want to move printer commands via printerport using socket programs.

Comment: That's only i am asking brother, how to move PJL,PCL, PS to printer?Help me brother !

Answer (score 0):

I found sdk for android [here](https://download.epson-biz.com/?service=pos). But This sdk is support only for Epson Printers (M-T88V, TM-T70 ,TM-P60
TM-U220 ). This is not used for other printers.

Thank You frndz..